# SMTP server not sending mail

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I got Message that **mail sent**. But in Inbox there is no new email i have found that email in 
`server inetpub-> mailroot-> Queue`

Please tell me the solution for this

Edited

```
 public  string  btnSendmail()
        {
            // System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer is obsolete in 2.0
            // System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is the alternate class for this in 2.0
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            try
            {
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("myemail@itaxsmart.com","");
                smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
                smtpClient.Port = 25;
                message.From = fromAddress;

                message.To.Add("mailsendtol@itaxsmart.com");
                message.Subject = "Feedback";


message.IsBodyHtml = false;
message.Body = "Hello World" ;
smtpClient.Send(message);
return  "Email successfully sent.";
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
{   return  "Send Email Failed." + ex.Message;
      }
```

Comment: no need to show your exact email and pwds if they are

Comment: i got Email on Sever-> Inetpub->mailroot->queue

Answer (score 0):

Is your SMTP started? If not, start it. If it is already started, try restarting it.

Also turn on logging and see if that helps.

Comment: relay-hosting.secureserver.net

Answer (score 0):

The moment asp.net manages to sent the message to the smtp server, you will get a success message. This only means that the message has reached your smtp server.

asp.net cannot control what your smtp server does with it.

Try using a public smtp server like gmail, if your local smtp server is giving trouble.

Comment: i m using pulic smtp that is   relay-hosting.secureserver.net

Answer (score 0):

Add This code to your web.config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"/>

      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

and Remove This

```
smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
smtpClient.Port = 25;
```

**Thanks,

Subhankar**

Comment: Relay Denied Form Server .i got  this Error

Comment: @rohanpanchal Where You have hosted that application? you have to try with that in hosted server, it shouldn't work in development environment. for example godaddy server.

Comment: Host my Site on Dedicated server but Using Goddedy SMPT Sever .